# Why the .a file is smaller than the .so file?

Tags: c++, cmake, android-ndk

the .a file and the .so file

[image]

the CMakeLists.txt

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.  Is is possible that all the real object code is in the .so file, and the .a file is simply the stub library used for linking?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File format differences between a static library (.a) and a shared library (.so)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879433/file-format-differences-between-a-static-library-a-and-a-shared-library-so)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `.a` file is a simple archive format for `.o` object files (which in turn are more or less a result of converting textual assembly into binary), while `.so` is a full-fledged ELF binary, which contains additional data sections and meta-data in the header.